# Google Chrome неправильно отображает картинку

Tags: html, css

В графических редакторах и во всех браузерах, кроме Google Chrome картинка отображается нормально, а в Google Chrome, какие-то белые пятна под  и над буквами.

[image]

Comment: В Safari под iOs вообще ссылка не открывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В хроме действительно белые полоски под буквами. Пересохрани картинку в Paint.NET (возможно и в других граф. редакторах, не проверял) и всё будет нормально.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Я пересохраняла и в paint.net и в фотошоп, этот эффект всё-таки не исчезает.

Comment: А если в image ready "сохранить для web" ?

Comment: masha2, у меня исчезает. Может Вы страницу не обновляли и картинка из кеша загружалась? Посмотрите вот эту - http://clck.ru/d/qwYJzBLD19Uf7

Comment: 7soft, спасибо. Кэш чистила. Вашу картинку поставила, сразу всё нормально отобразилось. Наверное, какой-то глюк у меня на компьютере с граф. редакторами.

Comment: [offtop]
Это вирус, он отслеживает изменение файла изображения и вставляет туда свой код, дабы потом проникнуть на уязвимую машину! Вуууу…
Тебе страшно? Мне нет. © Малыш и Карлсон
[/offtop]

Answer (score 2):

Ни на "картинках с людьми", ни "на длинной серой картинке вверху, где написано Russian Federation", я никаких различий, сравнивая эти же графичиские элементы в Осле, Опере, Огнелисе, Сафари и Хроме, не заметил.

P.S. Ничего не хочу сказать, но попахивает саморекламой. Такой прием, аля "*Ой, у меня какая-то точка в правом нижнем углу... Посмотрите тут - http://hashcode.ru/*", встречал уже не один десяток раз.

Comment: нет, белые пятна точно есть, уже у 2-х человек. Могу скрин выложить.

Comment: Эти пятна выглядят как небольшые тени, или снег над и под буквами и только в Хроме. Даже если я открываю в Гугл Хром одну картинку, уже наблюдается этот глюк.

Comment: Подтверждаю слова @Deonis - во всех браузерах всё одинаково отображается (на Mac OS, если что).

Comment: Я тестирую под windows.

Answer (score -2):

может стоит попробывать вставить <!DOCTYPE html> в самом начале файла, тогда возможно различий будет меньше